# Zoom Web Meeting SDK - Charges for meetings

Tags: zoom-sdk

This may be a silly question, but I can't seem to find a direct answer on Zoom's developer site. If I am developing and integrating an application for clients to allow them to schedule and manage webinars as a part of my regular (web based) business software offering, and then provide/distribute that application to my client for them to use, will the charges (from Zoom) for meetings and meeting time be made to THEIR Zoom account or to MY Zoom account? And is there a way for me to specify or configure whose account is billed for such time? Or is it all keyed to my own SDK key?

Comment: There will be no charges for WebSDK Integrations.

Comment: But for external Zoom user account access, you need to publish your App on Zoom Marketplace.